# indenting with ':g' command not working from the command line

Tags: normal-mode, invocation, global-command

When I need to work with some scrambled javascript/json code, one of my first steps is to introduce proper line breaks, followed by proper brace based indentation. For the later, I found the following command very helpful:

```
:%g/{/:normal $>i{
```

With at most a single opening brace on any line, this produces near perfect indentation in no time.

However, when trying to run the same command from the command line with the `-c` option, it simply does not seem to have any effect. I tried the following invocation:

```
vim -c ':%g/{/:normal $>i{' -c ':wq' some_scrambled_json_file.json
```

Why does this not work? And how do I need to change my invocation to make it work?

Comment: This is not a direct answer to your question but I think it is worth mentioning: use the right tool for what you want to do. If you want to fix the indentation of a json file non interactively you can use python eg `python -m json.tool bad.json > good.json` it will save you the trouble to use vim for something it is not intended to do. (I said python because that's what I use but you can do the same with any other scripting language)

Comment: @statox Yes, I know that there are other, probably better ways of achieving the same end. Nevertheless, this is an issue that I would not have expected or anticipated, and I'm quite curious to *understand* why the `:g` command behaves so much differently when invoked from the command line. So, I guess my main motivation for asking is, that I hope to become a better `vim` user that way...

Comment: Of course your question is absolutely legit and I wasn't criticizing it :) I specified that my comment was not an answer but just something I felt worth mentioning. About your question, I just tried your command and it seems to be working pretty well for me actually (in a cygwin shell)

Comment: @statox Curious. For me, it only presents the line-numbered file on the terminal as is (goes away after hitting space a few times to scroll through it), and does not change the file on disk at all. My distro is debian.

Comment: For what its worth [here is the result](https://imgur.com/FM93JKA) on a debian box of mine with vim 8.0... I have no idea what can cause your problem...

Comment: @statox Ok, so it must be some configuration issue. My `vim` version is 8.0 as well, but I guess we have some differences in our `.vimrc` files that make the difference. If nobody comes up with a bright idea soon, I guess, I'll just delete this question as its problem does not seem to be (easily) reproducible, and thus likely worthless to others. Anyway, thanks for your effort in checking :-)

Comment: You can always try to start vim without a vimrc (`-U NONE`) if it works well you can check [how to debug my vimrc?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/1841) And yes, wait a bit before deleting your question some people here are amazing vim experts, they might come up with a solution. Happy vimming :)